# Product of Sum of Digits

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

This is a bonus problem my teacher gave us during a competition math class:

> Is there a positive integer $n$ such that $S(n)S(n + 4)$ = $2022?$

The $S(n)$ means the sum of digits of $n.$ For example, if $n=14,$ then $S(n)=5$.

I've prime factorized $2022=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 337$ so far. And I've tried having $n=337$ and $n=666,$ both of which ended up fruitless.

I've realized that there needs to be lots of $9$s in the middle of the number to carry into $0$ but so far nothing has worked for me. Can I please have some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution comes from trials with the factors of $2022$:

$$S(n)=2022,S(n+4)=1\implies n+4=10^k\\n=10^k-4\implies S(n)=9k-3\\9k-3=2022\implies k=225$$

This gives our first solution: $$n=10^{225}-4$$

Other solutions exist, with $S(n+4)=3$, including Jean-Claude Arbaut's:
$$\begin{align}&n=10^{75}-2\\&n=2\times10^{75}-3\\&n=3\times10^{75}-4\end{align}$$
And infinitely many others, such as $n=21\times10^{75}-4$ or $n=111\times10^{75}-4$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a really good strategy!

Answer (score 5):

$$n=10^{75}-2$$

From $n\equiv S(n)\pmod{9}$ and $n+4\equiv S(n+4)\pmod{9}$, we must have $n(n+4)\equiv 2022\equiv 6\pmod{9}$ hence $n\equiv6$ or $8$ $\pmod{9}$. Then it's just trial and error with numbers with many nines.

Comment: Both answers were very useful, which one should I mark as accepted?

Comment: Can you show how did you get that number please?

Comment: @PlayGame I tested various values of $10^k-2$, by "bisecting" to find $2022$ for $S(n)S(n+4)$. Luckily, it worked. The idea was to try a number with many nines, that is $\equiv8\pmod9$. And numbers $10^k-2$ are the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

If there is such an $n$, then $n\equiv 6, 8 \pmod 9$ it follows easily from the fact that $n\equiv S(n)\pmod 9$. Can you show this?

Comment: why would $n\equiv 6, 8 \pmod 9$ be necessary?

Comment: First of all can you show that $S(n)\equiv n \pmod 9$?

Comment: Or since the test for divisibility by $9$ is the sum of digits, then yea

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot about that casting out nines.

Comment: You should get $n(n+4)\equiv 6 \pmod 9$ and it has only two solutions.

Comment: Oh...ok, got it, thanks!

Comment: Both answers were very useful, which one should I mark as accepted?